# The system cannot find the path specified in ecosysten.config.js deployment

Tags: node.js, iis, ssh, deployment, repo

I have created an `ecosystem.config.js` file to automate my deployment for my `Node.JS` `Strapi` application. I have specified a path on my external `Windows IIS server` where the application needs to be deployed. When running my deployment script it returns me an error: `The system cannot find the path specified`.

My `ecosystem.config.js` is like:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
      name: 'my-app',
      script: './server.js',
      args: 'start',
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: "production",
        //PORT: 8080
      },
      env_development: {
        NODE_ENV: "development",
        //PORT: 3000
      },
      out_file: "./out.log",
      error_file: "./error.log",
      merge_logs: true,
      log_date_format: "DD-MM HH:mm:ss Z",
      log_type: "json"
    }],
    deploy : {
       production : {
         user : "user",
         host : "host",
         ref  : "origin/main",
         repo : "git@github.com:githubrepo",
         path : "C:/Sites/application-folder/my-app-production",
         "post-deploy" : "npm install && NODE_ENV=production npm run build && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.config.js --env production"
       },
       development : {
        user : "user",
        host : "host",
        ref  : "origin/main",
        repo : "git@github.com:githubrepo",
        path : "C:/Sites/application-folder/my-app-staging",
        "post-deploy" : "npm install && NODE_ENV=development npm run build && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.config.js --env development"
      }
     }
};
```

On my `Windows IIS` I can navigate to this folder which is defined in path. For you information. When connecting via SSH I start in `C:\Users\User`. So I also tried to change the `path` object to `../../Sites/application-folder/my-app-staging` but this throws the same error. What am I doing wrong because I can navigate to the folder when connecting via `SSH`.

Comment: Please check that the user account you are using to deploy the application has the required permissions to access the path. If the user does not have permissions, you need to give the user account permissions to read and write the folder, or you can use an administrative account to deploy the application.

Comment: Hi, with this user I have this permissions. I can access the server via remote desktop with the same account and do all the things there. When connecting via SSH directly I can navigate to the folder and execute things. So i think that is not the problem

Comment: Have you tried manually deploying the application? Are there any issues with the deployment process? If manual deployment works, you may need to make some modifications to the deployment script.